# bootstrap 2.0 bootstrap-dropdown.js errors out when i add it to my js plugin lists

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

this is my current javascript includes

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery','application'  %>
```

its works fine but the moment i add the bootstrap-dropdown plugin.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery','bootstrap-transition','bootstrap-dropdown','application'%>
```

i get an error (firebug console) thats from the bootstrap-dropdown file.

```
--$("html").on is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)--
```

not too sure what I'm doing wrong here or what i did not catch/get.
oh btw the old bootstrap-dropdown worked for me.

Comment: sorry fixed it i missed using the latest jquery thats all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to upgrade to jQuery 1.7.1.